# Question on $\sigma -$algebra generated by 2 set.

Tags: probability

Let consider the experiment "launched a coin three times". Describes the experiment space and give a filtration adapted to the problem.

So if $H_i$ denote Heads at the i-th launched and $T_i$ denote tails at the i-th shot, the experiemnt space is $$\Omega =\{(H_1,H_2,H_3),(H_1,T_2,H_3),...\},$$
there is $2^3=8$ element. Now in the correction, the filtration is $$\mathcal F_1=\mathcal P(\Omega ),$$
$\mathcal F_2$ is the $\sigma -$algebra generated by $$A:=\{(H_1,H_2,H_3),(H_1,H_2,T_3),(H_1,T_2,H_3),(H_1,T_2,T_3)\}$$
and  $$B:=\{(T_1,H_2,H_3),(T_1,H_2,T_3),(T_1,T_2,H_3),(T_1,T_2,T_3)\}.$$

What does it mean ? That $\mathcal F_2=\{\emptyset, A,B,\Omega \}$ ?

Comment: Are there misprints? Is $\mathcal F_1$ actually $\mathcal F_3$ and is $\mathcal F_2$ actually $\mathcal F_1$? In any case, your suggestions are such that $\mathcal F_2\subset\mathcal F_1$ with $\mathcal F_2\ne\mathcal F_1$ hence these $\mathcal F_1$ and $\mathcal F_2$ cannot be part of a filtration (aka nondecreasing sequence of sigma-algebras).

Comment: @Did: that's why I asked what is $\mathcal F_2$ the $\sigma -$algebra generated by 2 set $A$ and $B$.  If you can read french, here is a link I read: http://www.bibmath.net/dico/index.php?action=affiche&quoi=./f/filtration.html

Comment: And it appears that $\mathcal F_1$ and $\mathcal F_2$ in your post stand for $\mathcal F_3$ and $\mathcal F_1$ respectively in the link. For example the link explicitely says that $\mathcal F_2$ is generated by **four** disjoint sets, not two.